# Telerik's reporting name space not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, telerik

I'm trying to use `Telerik` with `.NET framework 3.5` and `Visual Studio 2008`
I installed `Telerik Reporting` but when I try to use `Telerik.Reporting` I get error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Reporting' Doesn't exists in namespace 'Telerik' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

How can I solve this?

**EDIT**

I tried to add Reference but it prevents to be added (path is empty):

[image]

Comment: did you add the reference ? or are you sure `Telerik.Reporting.dll` exists in your reference and has property `Copy Local` to `true` ?

Comment: @AfnanAhmad: I just installed terelik using its installer! the dlls do exist in its installation path; but I didn't do anything more. how can I add reference? can you give me a hint on how to do that? ( link, instruction , etc); thanks

Comment: @Sinatr: excuse me; I corrected the misspells; In code these was correct; I wrote the question very fast which caused typo; in code it is `Telerik` as it is shown in error message;

Comment: I have posted an answer. Let me know if you need any further help and your problem still exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `Telerik.Reporting.dll` in References like following image:

[image]

Make a folder name Dependents and copy these files to this folder :

```
Telerik.Reporting
Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms
Telerik.Web.UI
```

Now click on References and then navigate to `Add Reference` and then a window will open. Browse to Folder Dependents and add all these `dlls`. Once `dlls` are added right click on them and make sure thier property `Copy Local` is set to `True`.

***Add Refrences***

[image]

***Select dlls from Folder. Please note you can have any name to this folder. This is just for the reason if you miss any references in the future you can add them again from this folder inside your project.***

[image]

***Right click to referenced dll and navigate to property here you can define `copy local` to `true`.***

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I did so, but after adding References it shows warnings! ( `Warning 50 The referenced component 'Telerik.Reporting' could not be found.` ) ; and i cant change local copy to true ! it resets every time

Comment: from where you have added the reference ? Did you make folder in your project and copied files there and added reference from there ?

Comment: Yes i created a References folder in my project and i'm loading files from there but after selecting these files they are added without Path property!!! can this be a problem of version incompatibility? (my Telerik is 2015 while my VS is 2008)

Comment: @RYN I think this cannot be the issue of VS. What version of .net you are using with your project ? I worked with .net 4.0 and it worked perfectly

Comment: I'm using .net 3.5;

Comment: Try using .net 4 or higher version.

Comment: Finding an old version of telerik solved the problem; thanks